# I am trying to register a user with parse but it keeps throwing JSONException, what could be wrong?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

```
saveUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        try {
            user.setUsername("12345");
            user.setPassword("1234");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Sign-up successful!
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Failed
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                           .setTitle("Oops try again!!!")
                           .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

> bad json response: org.json.JSONException: Value invalid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: at which line you are getting JSONException? please share that code too.

Comment: share code of ParseUser class.

Comment: Looks like you do not get a valid JSON

Comment: When invoking this method: user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {}

Comment: Why don't you just share code? that will be more helpful.

Comment: @activesince93 i am using a third party Parse API (Parse.com).

Comment: Then post your JSON response. Let's see that is correct or not.

Comment: @Ntombie have you initialize   Parse.initialize(this, YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_KEY); correctly?

Comment: @activesince93 The code above is the actual method used to send the details, When saving the details I get this error "bad json response: org.json.JSONException: Value invalid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject". I am not sure about your questin.

Comment: @AjayPandya yes I did.

Comment: your posted code in question doesn't show the exception in my view please check http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/

Comment: @Ajay i did follow the link and tried running this code locally and it works fine but still with the one that I have give the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `final` before ParseUser - since final variables are supposed to be immutable it should be like that:

`ParseUser user = new ParseUser();`

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked after I created a new project and didn't include final.